# No deadlock unless linked to pthreads?

Tags: c++, linker, pthreads, mutex, compiler-optimization

Why is it that creating a std::mutex deadlock will not actually cause a deadlock unless the program is linked to pthreads?

The following will deadlock when linked with pthreads library and will not deadlock if pthreads is not linked in. Tested on gcc and clang.

```
// clang++ main.cpp -std=c++14 -lpthread
#include <mutex>
int main() {
    std::mutex mtx;
    mtx.lock();
    mtx.lock();
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that without a thread library you don't actually need mutex functionality, but is the compiler aware of the libraries that are linked in? And can it optimized based on that?

Comment: fyi _"If lock is called by a thread that already owns the mutex, the behavior is undefined: ... "_ source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The following will deadlock when linked with pthreads library and will not deadlock if pthreads is not linked in.

That's because the default implementation of `std::mutex::lock` does *nothing*.

> is the compiler aware of the libraries that are linked in?

No: the compiler simply calls `std::mutex::lock` and passes it the address of `mtx`. It's the *implementation* of that function that behaves differently.

**Update:**

> To clarify, the implementation is able to change itself depending on if a library has been linked in? Through a macro?

By the time the compiler is done compiling, macro preprocessing is *also* done and can not have any further effect.

Perhaps it's best to demonstrate. Suppose you have:

```
int main() { return foo(); }
```

Can you tell what the result of execution of above program is? No, you can't, because you don't know what `foo` does.

Suppose now that I compile the following:

```
// foo.c
int foo() { return 0; }

gcc -c foo.c && ar ruv libfoo.a foo.o
gcc main.o -L. -lfoo
```

Now you can tell that the program will exit with `0` return code.

Now suppose that I also compile the following:

```
// bar.c
int foo() { abort(); }

gcc -c bar.c && ar ruv libbar.a bar.o
```

Finally, I link the same *unmodified* `main.o` like so:

```
gcc main.o -L. -lbar -lfoo
```

Can you tell what the resulting program will do?

You can: it will die with `SIGABRT` and produce a core dump.

Notice that `main.o` did not change, only the libraries that `main.o` is being linked against have changed.

This is exactly the same mechanism that causes your original program to behave differently depending on whether or not it is linked against `libpthread`.

Comment: To clarify, the implementation is able to change itself depending on if a library has been linked in? Through a macro?

Comment: Why does this allow multiple definitions of the same symbol?

Comment: @A-n-t-h-o-n-y There are no multiple definitions being linked in. To understand why this is so, you can read http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking